# Google Android ExpandableListView

Tags: android

How can I change the height indicator?

`android:indicatorEnd` and `android:indicatorStart` don't work?

```
 <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exListView"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="392dp"
        android:indicatorLeft="250dp"
        android:indicatorRight="300dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.11"
        android:indicatorEnd="10dp"
        android:indicatorStart="15dp" />
```

Comment: Did you try to remove android:indicatorLeft and android:indicatorRight and keep the ones with Start and End? or vice versa?

Comment: no i didn't, but i should also  set width this indicator.

Answer (score 1):

You can do fully customized indicator with follow up these steps:

1. Set `android:groupIndicator="@null"`

   ```
   <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/exListView"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="392dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.11"/>
   ```
2. Define imageview consider as `group_indicator` into `list_group_item.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#000000"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="8dp" >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/group_indicator"
       android:layout_width="30dip"
       android:layout_height="40dip"
       android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:textColor="#f9f93d"
       android:textSize="17dp" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Set group indicator image in your adapter  according to `isExpand()` method

   ```
   @Override

   public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
       if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
       }

       TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
       ImageView groupIndicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_indicator);
       lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
       lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
       if (isExpanded)
           groupIndicator.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
       else
           groupIndicator.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float);

       return convertView;
   }
   ```

This is a customized way of implementation to achieve that what we want 
It will help you completely!!
If it would be helpful to you then you can accept it.

Comment: If you got help from this stuff so accept this answer. You can do it.

Comment: you can add right this answer if you got any help from this.

Answer (score 0):

this is efficient way to set indicator attributes settings_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_empty="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="-30dp"
            android:top="120dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<item android:state_expanded="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="-30dp"
            android:top="120dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up"
             >
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Used into:

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector"
   />
```

Comment: Gave you another answer please check it.